How to pass a lot of objects (10000 or more) to a shader?
If you need additional information, please ask me
I want to draw all objects that are displayed on the screen by the shader with one request.
Now I have to switch the shader between objects and it is very slow, I can win 100+ frames with this optimization.
I read about FBO, but I somehow need to find these objects on the texture written in FBO, so I started looking for how to pass a bunch of positions and other information to the shader.
I found out that it can be passed through the texture, but there are some difficulties here too.
As I understand it, I need to write an array of bytes to the texture, because my coordinates are in f32.
I was able to write it, but I don’t understand how to extract it at all.
There is very little information on glsl on the Internet, I don’t know why.
use macroquad::prelude::*;

#[macroquad::main("Texture")]
async fn main() {
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = vec![
        0, 255, 0, 255,
        255, 255, 0, 255,
        255, 0, 0, 255,
        255, 0, 255, 255
    ];
    let texture = Texture2D::from_rgba8(2, 2, &bytes); // here i write rgba array, but need write bytes of f32 array like [6.20, 50.31231, 44.1213, 994.44]

    let lens_material = load_material(
        ShaderSource::Glsl {
            vertex: VERTEX_SHADER,
            fragment: FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        },
        MaterialParams {
            uniforms: vec![
                UniformDesc::new("Size", UniformType::Float2),
                UniformDesc::new("Position", UniformType::Float2)
            ],
            textures: vec!["MyTexture".to_string()],
            ..Default::default()
        },
    )
        .unwrap();

    let size = vec2(300., 300.);
    let pos1 = vec2(screen_width()/2. - size.x / 8., screen_height()/2. - size.y / 8.);
    let mut pos2 = vec2(screen_width()/2. - size.x / 2., screen_height()/2. - size.y / 2.);


    let positions = vec![pos1, pos2];
    let bounds = vec2(14000., 14000.); // Position bounds
    let normalized_positions: Vec<Vec2> = positions.iter().map(|&p| p / bounds * 255.).collect();




    dbg!(normalized_positions);

    dbg!(screen_width(), screen_height());

    loop {
        clear_background(WHITE);


        lens_material.set_texture("MyTexture", texture.clone());
        lens_material.set_uniform("Size", size);
        lens_material.set_uniform("Position", pos1 + size / 2.);

        // Rect
        gl_use_material(&lens_material); {
            draw_rectangle(pos1.x, pos1.y, size.x, size.y, WHITE);
        } gl_use_default_material();

        draw_circle(screen_width() / 2., screen_height()/2., 60., PURPLE);
        lens_material.set_texture("MyTexture", texture.clone());
        lens_material.set_uniform("Size", size / 2.);
        lens_material.set_uniform("Position", pos2);

        // Circle
        gl_use_material(&lens_material); {
            draw_circle(pos2.x, pos2.y, size.x / 2., WHITE);
        } gl_use_default_material();


        next_frame().await;
    }
}

const FRAGMENT_SHADER: &'static str = r#"
    #version 300 es

    #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
    #endif

    uniform sampler2D MyTexture;

    in vec2 uv;
    out vec4 FragColor;

    void main() {
        float dist = length(uv - vec2(0.5, 0.5));

        // if (dist < 0.5) {
            vec4 texColor = texture(MyTexture, uv);
            FragColor = texColor;
        // }
    }
"#;

const VERTEX_SHADER: &'static str = r#"
    #version 300 es

    #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
    #endif

    uniform vec2 Size;
    uniform vec2 Position;

    in vec2 position;
    uniform mat4 Projection;
    uniform mat4 Model;

    out vec2 uv;

    void main() {
        gl_Position = Projection * Model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.);

        vec2 normalizedPosition = (position - Position) / Size * 0.5 + 0.5; // [0; 1]
        uv = normalizedPosition;
    }
"#;

Update for Aleksey comment:
The objects are all the same shape (circle), I would like to understand the basic principle of transmission, then I can probably pull it off, if necessary.
I already transmit a number of other data via uniforms, but the limit of 4096 is too small for the current task.
The example you attached seems to work with uniforms, but I also saw an example with an instance and textures.
However, I do not understand how opengl understands that there is an object in front of it, if in fact it is transmitted pieces of the screen?
Let's say the entire screen is white and there are 3 red circles on it, will gl_InstanceID go through them all?
I try this way, but because I do not understand how it works.
After reading it again, now it seems to me that InstanceID is the number of the current packet.
let size = vec2(300., 300);
let pos1 = vec2(screen_width()/2. - size.x / 8., screen_height()/2. - size.y / 8.);
 let mut pos2 = vec2(screen_width()/2. - size.x / 2., screen_height()/2. - size.y / 2.);

 let positions: Vec<f32> = vec![ 
pos1.x, // Pos 1 
pos1.y, // Pos 1 
0.0, // Pos 1 
0.0, // Pos 1 
pos2.x, // Pos 2 
pos2.y, // Pos 2 
0.0, // Pos 2 
0.0 // Pos 2 
];

 let mut bytes: [u8; 64] = [0u8; 64];
 let pos_bytes: &[u8] = bytemuck::cast_slice(&positions);

 for (i, &byte) in pos_bytes.iter().enumerate() { bytes[i] = byte;
 } let positions_texture = Texture2D::from_rgba8(4, 4, &bytes);

lens_material.set_texture("PositionsTexture", positions_texture.clone());

vertex:

 void main() { gl_Position = Projection * Model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.);

 vec4 Position = texture(PositionsTexture, vec2(gl_InstanceID, gl_InstanceID));

 vec2 normalizedPosition = (position - Position.xy) / Size * 0.5 + 0.5; // [0; 1] uv = normalizedPosition;
 } 


To render multiple objects with same appearance in one draw call (e.g. 1000 quads with same texture), you need instancing. To render many different objects of different geometries and textures with one draw call - that will require complex architecture of the application, I'm afraid far beyond your current OpenGL skills

@AlexeyS.Larionov I answered in the body of the question because there are too many characters.

Why is this using macroquad instead of interacting with the OpenGL API directly? Why do you need "to find these objects on the texture written in FBO" instead of storing objects in VBOs? Why does it need to be passed to the GPU using a texture? Overall, what you really trying to accomplish, in terms of visual output (and input)? I'm almost certain that there's a better way.

I did a lot of work and here is the result.
In order to correctly transfer the positions, you need to convert them to byte representation.
In order to extract them, you need to know what format of float values ​​Rust uses - IEEE 754.
Next, on the shader side, you need to restore the float value from the bytes, it is also restored with a small error - so you need to round the bytes up using round.
I hope this will make someone's life easier, because I have passed 75% of hell, but my task is not completely finished.
use macroquad::prelude::*;
use macroquad::prelude::FilterMode::Nearest;

#[macroquad::main("Texture")]
async fn main() {

    let bytes8: Vec<u8> = vec![
        0, 255, 0, 255, // Green
        255, 255, 0, 255, // Yellow
        255, 0, 0, 255, // Red
        255, 0, 255, 255 // Purple +-
    ];

    let texture = Texture2D::from_rgba8(2, 2, &bytemuck::cast_slice(&bytes8));
    texture.set_filter(Nearest);

    let material = load_material(
        ShaderSource::Glsl {
            vertex: VERTEX_SHADER,
            fragment: FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        },
        MaterialParams {
            uniforms: vec![
                UniformDesc::new("Size", UniformType::Float2),
                UniformDesc::new("Position", UniformType::Float2)
            ],
            textures: vec![
                "MyTexture".to_string(),
                "MyTexture2".to_string(),
            ],
            ..Default::default()
        },
    )
        .unwrap();

    let size = vec2(300., 300.);
    let pos1 = vec2(200., 222.);
    let pos2 = vec2(600., 300.);

    let positions_buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![
        vec2(pos1.x, pos1.y),
        vec2(pos2.x, pos2.y)
    ]
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|p| [
            p.x.to_le_bytes(),
            p.y.to_le_bytes(),
        ])
        .flatten()
        .collect();

    let width = 4;
    let height = 1;

    let texture2 = Texture2D::from_rgba8(width as u16, height as u16, &positions_buffer);
    texture2.set_filter(Nearest);

    loop {
        clear_background(WHITE);

        material.set_texture("MyTexture", texture.clone());
        material.set_texture("MyTexture2", texture2.clone());
        material.set_uniform("Size", size);
        material.set_uniform("Position", pos1);

        gl_use_material(&material); {
            draw_circle(pos1.x, pos1.y, size.x / 2., WHITE);
        } gl_use_default_material();

        gl_use_material(&material); {
            draw_circle(pos2.x, pos2.y, size.x / 2., WHITE);
        } gl_use_default_material();

        next_frame().await;
    }
}

const FRAGMENT_SHADER: &'static str = r#"
    #version 300 es

    #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
    #endif

    uniform sampler2D MyTexture;

    in vec2 uv;
    out vec4 FragColor;

    void main() {
        vec4 texColor = texture(MyTexture, uv);
        FragColor = texColor;
    }
"#;

const VERTEX_SHADER: &'static str = r#"
    #version 300 es

    #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
    #endif

    uniform vec2 Size;
    uniform vec2 Position;

    in vec2 position;
    uniform mat4 Projection;
    uniform mat4 Model;

    out vec2 uv;

    uniform sampler2D MyTexture2;

    // Float from bytes in IEEE 754 format
    float bytesToFloat32(int b0, int b1, int b2, int b3) {
        int intBits = (b0) | (b1 << 8) | (b2 << 16) | (b3 << 24);
        float sign = ((intBits >> 31) == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
        int exponent = ((intBits >> 23) & 0xFF) - 127;
        int mantissaBits = intBits & 0x7FFFFF;

        float mantissa = 1.0;
        float power = 0.5;

        for (int i = 22; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ((mantissaBits & (1 << i)) != 0) {
                mantissa += power;
            }
            power *= 0.5;
        }

        return sign * mantissa * pow(2.0, float(exponent));
    }

    vec4 getBytesFromTexture(float index) {
        vec2 uv = vec2(index, 1.);
        vec4 Bytes = texture(MyTexture2, uv);

        return Bytes * 255.;
    }

    in vec2 aOffset;

    void main() {

        gl_Position = Projection * Model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.);

        int width = 4;
        float step = 1. / float(width);

        for (int i = 0; i < width / 2; i+=2) {
            vec4 X = getBytesFromTexture(step * float(i));
            vec4 Y = getBytesFromTexture(step * float(i+1));

            float x = bytesToFloat32(int(round(X.x)), int(round(X.y)), int(round(X.z)), int(round(X.w)));
            float y = bytesToFloat32(int(round(Y.x)), int(round(Y.y)), int(round(Y.z)), int(round(Y.w)));

            vec2 Position = vec2(x, y);

            vec2 normalizedPosition = (position - Position) / Size * 0.5 + 0.5; // [0; 1]
            uv = normalizedPosition;
        }

    }
"#;

